# C# - Highlight Current Line

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C#, and I am creating a notepad type of application. It's working good, but I would like to highlight the current line - meaning the current line where the cursor is or where the mouse has been clicked on would be highlighted in another color. I haven't worked with colors in C# so far, so any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Care to share what control is used to display the text editing area? E.g. A custom one based on RichTextBox or ... ?

Comment: Not a real question: there is nothing that can be answered here. I would suggest: decide the technology (WinForms or WPF). Then get a book that covers that technology at a detailed level (e.g. "Programming Microsoft Windows with C#", Petzold for WinForms at a basic drawing level.

Comment: You should add more details on what you have done so far. Are you creating a new control? Customizing TextBox? RichTextBox?

Comment: A rich text box works almost entirely off of the "selection". Use the methods of the RTB to select the range of text you want to change, and then set the selection color to whatever color you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check [CodeProject articles for Edit controls](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/).

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot to mention I am using a rich text box for text-editing.

I looked around CodeProject but I didn't find anything I need over there.